# Salesforce Trigger - Prevent Parent Case Closure if Parent Case has open Child Cases

Tags: triggers, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have the following Apex trigger which should prevent a Parent Case from closing if the parent case has open child cases.  Kindly assist with trouble shooting as the Apex Trigger is not firing.

```
trigger CaseTriggerCloseChild on Case ( before update ) {
    
    Set < Id > setCaseIds = new Set < Id >();
    Map < Id, Integer > mapOpenCaseCount = new Map < Id, Integer >();
    
    for ( Case objCase : trigger.new ) {
        
        if ( objCase.Status == 'Closed' ) {
            setCaseIds.add( objCase.Id );
        }
    }
    
    for ( Case objCase : [ SELECT ParentId FROM Case WHERE ParentId IN: setCaseIds AND IsClosed = false ] ) {
    
        if ( mapOpenCaseCount.containsKey( objCase.ParentId ) ) {
        
            mapOpenCaseCount.put( objCase.ParentId, mapOpenCaseCount.get( objCase.ParentId ) + 1 );
        
        } else {
            mapOpenCaseCount.put( objCase.ParentId, 1 );
        }
    }    
    
    
    for ( Case objCase : trigger.new ) {
    
        if ( objCase.Status == 'Closed' ) {
        
            if ( mapOpenCaseCount.containsKey( objCase.Id ) ) {
        
                objCase.addError( 'You cannot close this Case. It has ' + mapOpenCaseCount.get( objCase.Id ) + ' open Child Cases.' );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your map of open cases is keyed on the parent ID and you are using the current case ID to look for open cases. You'll need to restructure it some.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, much appreciated.  I added a "Related Cases" related list on the page layout as I initially did not have this, i only had a "Cases" related list.  After doing that, the trigger is now firing.